# Create file on unmounted folder

Tags: unix, mount

What happen if we try to create a file on a unmounted folder?
Does the file is created on local system?

I have a mounted folder that could sometimes unmount for reasons

I'm going to schedule a oracle procedure that writes a file inside there, what will happen if somehow the folder is unmounted

Comment: The file was created locally, and after if you mount the distant folder your locally file could be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the file is created on local system?

Yes. Or, better, the file is created *into* that directory (don't call *folder* unix directories... :)), wherever that directory is (it could be part of a mounted remote file system, in that case it was not part of the local system).

Writing permissions on the directory play a role, and the mount command can also play with those permissions, but this is another, complicated matter.

Comment: Thank you
I'll try to not repeat 'folder' again ;)